# Using Notepad++ i am trying to change a string of numbers and letters like a MAC address to have the Semicolons in between every two characters

Tags: notepad++, string

Using Notepad++ I am trying to change a string of numbers and letters like a MAC address to have a Semicolon in between every two characters and then a Comma between each MAC address and put them all in one row.

so it would go from this
0004F23E7EF4
0004F23E8D46
to
00:04:F2:3E:7E:F4, 00:04:F2:3E:8D:46,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? SU isn't a script/regex writing service.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `..(?=..)`
- Replace with: `$0:`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
..          # 2 characters
(?=..)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have 2 characters after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          # the whole match
:           # a colon
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]